# Move XML attributes to style="" in HTML files

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to replace standalone attributes `width="<>"` and `height="<>"` with `style="width:<>; height:<>;`.

A typical input is the following

```
<img width="32pt" alt="PIC" class="graphics" height="32pt" src="images/about.png"/>
```

Thus the result should be

```
<img style="width:32pt; height:32pt;" alt="PIC" class="graphics" src="images/about.png"/>
```

The problem is that I've never worked with xsl before.

What I know, as far, is that

this can catch the img element

```
<xsl:template match="xh:img">
```

this can catch the `width` attribute

```
<xsl:template match="@width">
```

and I know how to add an attribute or element.
But I don't know how to store the value of the `width` and `height` and write both in a single line.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
<xsl:template match="img">
    <img style="width:{@width}; height:{@height};">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='width' or name()='height')]"/>
    </img>
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming every `img` has both `width` and `height` attributes, and no child nodes. If your source XML places the `img` elements in a namespace (not shown in your question), add the appropriate prefix to the template's match pattern.

For reference, see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#attribute-value-templates

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to fix the ")" of the `not()` putting it at the end, but it works.

Comment: Good catch - fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You (or other readers) may be interested in this more general (XSLT 2.0) solution taken from a production stylesheet:

```
  <xsl:template name="style-attributes">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@style | @class">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@style | @class"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@*[f:is-style-attribute(.)]">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
          <xsl:for-each select="@*[f:is-style-attribute(.)]">
            <xsl:if test="position() gt 1">; </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="style-attribute"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="f:is-style-attribute" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="att" as="attribute(*)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="n" select="local-name($att)"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="namespace-uri($att) = '' and $n = ('class', 'style', 'border', 'width', 'cellspacing', 'padding', 'cellpadding', 'align', 'valign')"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="f:units" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="if ($value castable as xs:integer) then concat($value, 'px') else $value"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="@border" mode="style-attribute">border:<xsl:value-of select="f:units(.)"/> solid</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@width" mode="style-attribute">width:<xsl:value-of select="f:units(.)"/></xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@align" mode="style-attribute">text-align:<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@valign" mode="style-attribute">vertical-align:<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@cellspacing" mode="style-attribute">border-spacing:<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@padding" mode="style-attribute">padding:<xsl:value-of select="f:units(.)"/></xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@cellpadding" mode="style-attribute">padding:<xsl:value-of select="f:units(.)"/></xsl:template>
  ... etc (as required)
```